# Combining pipes and the magrittr dot (.) placeholder

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am fairly new to R and I am trying to understand the `%>%` operator and the usage of the " `.`" (dot) placeholder. As a simple example the following code works

```
library(magrittr)
library(ensurer)
ensure_data.frame <- ensures_that(is.data.frame(.))
data.frame(x = 5) %>% ensure_data.frame
```

However the following code fails

```
ensure_data.frame <- ensures_that(. %>% is.data.frame)
data.frame(x = 5) %>% ensure_data.frame
```

where I am now piping the placeholder into the is.data.frame method.

I am guessing that it is my understanding of the limitations/interpretation of the dot placeholder that is lagging, but can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "problem" is that magrittr has a short-hand notation for anonymous functions:

```
. %>% is.data.frame
```

is roughly the same as

```
function(.) is.data.frame(.)
```

In other words, when the dot is the (left-most) left-hand side, the pipe has special behaviour.

You can escape the behaviour in a few ways, e.g.

```
(.) %>% is.data.frame
```

or any other way where the LHS is not identical to `.`
In this particular example, this may seem as undesirable behaviuour, but commonly in examples like this there's really no need to pipe the first expression, so `is.data.frame(.)` is as expressive as `. %>% is.data.frame`, and
examples like

```
data %>% 
some_action %>% 
lapply(. %>% some_other_action %>% final_action)
```

can be argued to be clearner than

```
data %>% 
some_action %>%
lapply(function(.) final_action(some_other_action(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
. = data.frame(x = 5)
a = data.frame(x = 5)

a %>% is.data.frame
#[1] TRUE
. %>% is.data.frame
#Functional sequence with the following components:
#
# 1. is.data.frame(.)
#
#Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

Looks like a bug to me, but `dplyr` experts can chime in.

A simple workaround in your expression is to do `.[] %>% is.data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that it might be an inconsistency in dplyr and for the workaround!