# R: combine several gsub() function in a pipe

Tags: r, pipeline, gsub

To clean some messy data I would like to start using pipes `%>%`, but I fail to get the R code working if `gsub()` is not at the beginning of the pipe, should occur late (Note: this question is not concerned with proper import, but with data cleaning).

Simple example:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(A= c("2.187,78 ", "5.491,28 ", "7.000,32 "), B = c("A","B","C"))
```

Column A contains characters (in this case numbers, but this also could be string) and need to be cleaned.
The steps are

```
df$D <- gsub("\\.","",df$A)
df$D <- str_trim(df$D) 
df$D <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".",df$D))
```

One easily could pipe this

```
df$D  <-  gsub("\\.","",df$A) %>%
          str_trim() %>%
          as.numeric(gsub(",", ".")) %>%
```

The problem is the second gsub because it asks for the Input .... which actually the result of the previous line.

Please, could anyone explain how to use functions like gsub() further down the pipeline? 
Thanks a lot!

system: R 3.2.3, Windows

Comment: Mention the external packages you are using.

Comment: Though not with gsub you could use `df$D  <-  gsub("\\.","",df$A) %>% str_trim() %>% str_replace(',', '.')`

Comment: Actually, this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716710/combining-pipes-and-the-dot-placeholder-in-r

Comment: You don't actually need to trim whitespace for `as.numeric` to work.

Comment: external packages: dplyr,magrittr,stringr. Thanks for the advice with str_replace(',', '.') and whitespace & as.numeric

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)

df$D <- df$A %>%
  { gsub("\\.","", .) } %>%
  str_trim() %>%
  { as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", .)) }
```

With pipe your data are passed as a **first** argument to the next function, so if you want to use it somewhere else you need to wrap the next line in `{}` and use `.` as a data "marker".

Comment: Ah, thanks, that is the basic functionality that I missed. Thanks a lot for explaining this!

Comment: Remember that you can also use `.` multiple times.

Comment: But as shown in my answer it is not necessary to use `.`.

Comment: @ddiez, `{ gsub("\\.","", .) }` is much shorter than `gsub(pattern = "\\.", replacement="")`, and equally readable for me.

Comment: @m-dz you are right. But to be honest I do not like much either your answer or mine. Somehow prefer G. Grothendieck's solution(s).

Comment: @ddiez, haha, that's true. See my comment under his answer. I am used to `data.table` syntax and modify by reference, that's why I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 10):

Normally one applies the pipes to the data frame as a whole like this returning the cleaned data frame.  The idea of functional programming is that objects are immutable and are not changed in place but rather new objects are generated.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate(C = gsub("\\.", "", A)) %>%
   mutate(C = gsub(",", ".", C)) %>%
   mutate(C = as.numeric(C))
```

Also note that these alternatives work:

```
df %>% mutate(C = gsub("\\.", "", A), C = gsub(",", ".", C), C = as.numeric(C))


df %>% mutate(C = read.table(text = gsub("[.]", "", A), dec = ",")[[1]])


df %>% mutate(C = type.convert(gsub("[.]", "", A), dec = ","))
```

For this particular example `type.convert` seems the most appropriate since it compactly expresses at a high level what we intend to do.   In comparison, the gsub/as.numeric solutions seem too low level and verbose while read.table adds conversion to data.frame which we need to undo making it too high level.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the argument that is fed into the pipe needs to be the first in the list of arguments. But this is not the case for `gsub()`, as `x` is the third one. A (wordy) workaround could be:

```
df$A %>% 
  gsub(pattern = "\\.", replacement="") %>%
  str_trim() %>%
  gsub(patter = ",", replacement = ".") %>%
  as.numeric
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html) from package **stringr** as a drop-in replacement for `gsub`. stringr functions follow a tidy approach in which the string / character vector is the first argument.

```
c("hello", "hi") %>% str_replace_all("[aeiou]", "x")
```

See [Introduction to stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/stringr.html) for more information on stringr's sensibly named and defined functions as replacements for R's default string functions.