# Using gsub in combination with filter() and grepl()

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, gsub

I am trying to replace all `Normal1, Normal2, Normal3` with `Normal` .

`df=data.frame(col1=1:4, col2=c("Normal", "Normal2", "Normal3", "Normal"))`

when I try this `df %>% filter(grepl("^Nor", col2)) %>% gsub("Normal.*","Normal", df$col2)`

`Warning message:
In gsub(., "Normal.*", "Normal", df$col2) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

How to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: There's really no need to use `filter` here, just use `df$col2 = gsub("Normal.*","Normal", df$col2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two concepts involved here:

1. When you're piping the data, `%>%` is telling the next function to use the data resulting from `filter(grepl("^Nor", col2))` as the **first** argument to the next function. [`gsub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)'s argument list is ordered differently than `tidyverse` functions:

> grep, grepl, regexpr, gregexpr and regexec search for matches to argument pattern within each element of a character vector: they differ in the format of and amount of detail in the results. sub and gsub perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively.
>
> gsub(pattern, replacement, **x**, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, 
>            fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

So, the **x** argument is where the vector you're trying to replace "Normal" values belongs in the function. `gsub` doesn't realize you're trying to put the data somewhere other than the first argument.

2. gsub works on a column of data, and what you're passing it is a dataframe. As-is, your pipeline has:

   - Step 1: Dataframe
   - Step 2: Dataframe
   - Step 3: Vector

You *could* get fancy with the data structures in order to expose gsub as a direct participant in the pipe (as you've got it now). [m-dz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4272484/m-dz)'s answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997273/r-combine-several-gsub-function-ina-pipe) walks through how to do that. Essentially, you need to tell your code that it should pass the data argument from the previous step somewhere *other than the first argument of the next function.*

That said, I would highly recommend the approach that [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) suggests. Specifically, placing the data cleaning you're doing with `gsub` in a `mutate` function.

There are a few reasons why I think this is a better approach:

1. It's explicit - many people use `dplyr`, and are aware of what `mutate` does. By putting your data cleaning step into `mutate`, you're saying to others (including [future you](https://www.r-bloggers.com/your-most-valuable-collaborator-future-you/)): "in this step, I am modifying `col2`, and here's how I am modifying it."
2. It makes passing the data to an arbitrary place in `gsub` easier. In `mutate`, the data argument is the first argument, **and** it exposes that argument to functions which define/modify the dataframe. That makes it easy to refer to the data at places in a function other than the first argument.

---

I built a reproducible example from the `iris` dataset:

```
iris %>%
    # create a fake "col2" to demonstrate Normal1, Normal2, Normal3
    mutate(
        options = runif(nrow(iris)),
        col2 = ifelse(options  > 0.333, "Normal2", "Normal1"),
        col2 = ifelse(options > 0.666, "Normal3", col2),
        options = NULL) %>%
    filter(grepl("virginica", .$Species)) %>%
    # example of how wrapping gsub in mutate can accomplish the goal
    mutate(col2 = gsub("Normal.*", "Normal", .$col2))
```

---

**An alternative to `mutate()`**

If you're really committed to not using `mutate`, you could also write your own function wrapping a call to gsub and taking a dataframe as its first argument. An example could look like this:

```
gsub_dataframe <- function(data, pattern, replacement, column) {
    data[column] <- gsub(pattern, replacement, data[[column]])
    return(data)
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this, though, because it adds more custom code to an analysis pipeline and the `mutate` based solution does the same thing and other users are already familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Bethke for you comprehensive explanation. My knowledge of coding is very naive compare to you and others here since I am a biologist, but I wish it was much simpler way to do this. because quite often I need to change variables like this in my data. But you answer is much appreciated !

Comment: No problem! Yeah, R's interesting because there are a lot of different ways to accomplish the same tasks. Ultimately, as long as it's doing what you need it to that's great!