# Meaning of error using . shorthand inside dplyr function

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm getting a `dplyr::bind_rows` error. It's a very trivial problem, because I can easily get around it, but I'd like to understand the meaning of the error message.

I have the following data of some population groups for New England states, and I'd like to bind on a copy of these same values with the name changed to "New England," so that I can group by name and add them up, giving me values for the individual states, plus an overall value for the region.

```r
df <- structure(list(name = c("CT", "MA", "ME", "NH", "RI", "VT"), 
        estimate = c(501074, 1057316, 47369, 76630, 141206, 27464)),
        class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I'm doing this as part of a much larger flow of piped steps, so I can't just do `bind_rows(df, df %>% mutate(name = "New England"))`. `dplyr` gives the convenient `.` shorthand for a data frame being piped from one function to the next, but I can't use that to bind the data frame to itself in a way I'd like.

What *does* work and gets me the output I want:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  # arbitrary piped operation
  mutate(name = str_to_lower(name)) %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(., name = "New England")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(estimate = sum(estimate))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   name        estimate
#>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 ct            501074
#> 2 ma           1057316
#> 3 me             47369
#> 4 New England  1851059
#> 5 nh             76630
#> 6 ri            141206
#> 7 vt             27464
```

But when I try to do the same thing with the `.` shorthand, I get this error:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(name = str_to_lower(name)) %>%
  bind_rows(. %>% mutate(name = "New England"))
#> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id): Argument 2 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a fseq/function
```

Like I said, doing it the first way is fine, but I'd like to understand the error because I write a lot of multi-step piped code.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716710/combining-pipes-and-the-dot-placeholder-in-r)

Comment: @aosmith Thank you, one of the answers there—enclosing the `.` in parentheses—does indeed take care of the error. I'd vote to close my own question as a dupe, except I would like some insight into the error message itself

Comment: I think the info in that answer sheds some light on your error.  It looks like using the dot in magrittr like `. %>% functionname` is shorthand for an anonymous function.  Your error is telling you that - you are trying to pass an anonymous function to the second argument of `bind_rows` but it expects a data.frame.

Comment: For example, look at the error you get for `bind_rows(mtcars, sum)`

Comment: @aosmith Thanks, I hadn't realized it created an anonymous function. Feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @aosmith noted in the comments it's due to the way `magrittr` parses the dot in this case :

from `?'%>%'`:

> **Using the dot-place holder as lhs**
>
> When the dot is used as lhs, the
>   result will be a functional sequence, i.e. a function which applies
>   the entire chain of right-hand sides in turn to its input.

To avoid triggering this, any modification of the expression on the lhs will do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(name = str_to_lower(name)) %>%
  bind_rows((.) %>% mutate(name = "New England"))

df %>%
  mutate(name = str_to_lower(name)) %>%
  bind_rows({.} %>% mutate(name = "New England"))

df %>%
  mutate(name = str_to_lower(name)) %>%
  bind_rows(identity(.) %>% mutate(name = "New England"))
```

Here's a suggestion that avoid the problem altogether:

```
df %>%
  # arbitrary piped operation
  mutate(name = str_to_lower(name)) %>%
  replicate(2,.,simplify = FALSE) %>%
  map_at(2,mutate_at,"name",~"New England") %>%
  bind_rows

# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#    name        estimate
#    <chr>          <dbl>
#  1 ct            501074
#  2 ma           1057316
#  3 me             47369
#  4 nh             76630
#  5 ri            141206
#  6 vt             27464
#  7 New England   501074
#  8 New England  1057316
#  9 New England    47369
# 10 New England    76630
# 11 New England   141206
# 12 New England    27464
```