# Nested pipe chain in dplyr / left_join

Tags: r, dplyr

In the process of trying to get a grouped lag variable (which isn't possible just using `lag`), the suggested solution was to pull the data out, lag the distinct rows, and then re-join it.

I prefer to do this without creating intermediate objects, and would like to do it in the midst of a chain.  However it doesn't seem to work as I would expect, and the problem seems to be some interaction between using the `.` and the nested chain inside the left_join.

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
df <- data.frame(Team = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"),
                 Date = c("2016-05-10","2016-05-10", "2016-05-10", "2016-05-10",
                          "2016-05-12", "2016-05-12", "2016-05-12",
                          "2016-05-15","2016-05-15",
                          "2016-05-30", "2016-05-30"), 
                 Points = c(1,4,3,2,1,5,6,1,2,3,9)
)


#This works:
df %>% left_join(x = ., y = df %>% 
                   distinct(Team, Date) %>% 
                   mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)))
#> Joining, by = c("Team", "Date")
#>    Team       Date Points Date_Lagged
#> 1     A 2016-05-10      1        <NA>
#> 2     A 2016-05-10      4        <NA>
#> 3     A 2016-05-10      3        <NA>
#> 4     A 2016-05-10      2        <NA>
#> 5     B 2016-05-12      1  2016-05-10
#> 6     B 2016-05-12      5  2016-05-10
#> 7     B 2016-05-12      6  2016-05-10
#> 8     C 2016-05-15      1  2016-05-12
#> 9     C 2016-05-15      2  2016-05-12
#> 10    D 2016-05-30      3  2016-05-15
#> 11    D 2016-05-30      9  2016-05-15

#And this works:
df %>% left_join(x = ., y = .)
#> Joining, by = c("Team", "Date", "Points")
#>    Team       Date Points
#> 1     A 2016-05-10      1
#> 2     A 2016-05-10      4
#> 3     A 2016-05-10      3
#> 4     A 2016-05-10      2
#> 5     B 2016-05-12      1
#> 6     B 2016-05-12      5
#> 7     B 2016-05-12      6
#> 8     C 2016-05-15      1
#> 9     C 2016-05-15      2
#> 10    D 2016-05-30      3
#> 11    D 2016-05-30      9

#This doesn't work despite the fact that `.` is df.  
df %>% left_join(x = ., y = . %>% 
                   distinct(Team, Date) %>% 
                   mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)))
#> Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars"): no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('fseq', 'function')"



#Desired output
distinct(df, Team, Date) %>%
  mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)) %>%
  right_join(., df) %>%
  select(Team, Date, Points, Date_Lagged)
#> Joining, by = c("Team", "Date")
#>    Team       Date Points Date_Lagged
#> 1     A 2016-05-10      1        <NA>
#> 2     A 2016-05-10      4        <NA>
#> 3     A 2016-05-10      3        <NA>
#> 4     A 2016-05-10      2        <NA>
#> 5     B 2016-05-12      1  2016-05-10
#> 6     B 2016-05-12      5  2016-05-10
#> 7     B 2016-05-12      6  2016-05-10
#> 8     C 2016-05-15      1  2016-05-12
#> 9     C 2016-05-15      2  2016-05-12
#> 10    D 2016-05-30      3  2016-05-15
#> 11    D 2016-05-30      9  2016-05-15
```

Created on 2018-06-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: your . is in the wrong location `left_join(distinct(., Team, Date)`

Comment: You can't use `. %>%` in the way you intend to, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729045/meaning-of-error-using-shorthand-inside-dplyr-function/50789260#50789260

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your code to work, you will need a curly brace around the `y` argument as shown below

```
  df %>% left_join(x = ., y = {.} %>% 
                   distinct(Team, Date) %>% 
                   mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)))

Joining, by = c("Team", "Date")
   Team       Date Points Date_Lagged
1     A 2016-05-10      1        <NA>
2     A 2016-05-10      4        <NA>
3     A 2016-05-10      3        <NA>
4     A 2016-05-10      2        <NA>
5     B 2016-05-12      1  2016-05-10
6     B 2016-05-12      5  2016-05-10
7     B 2016-05-12      6  2016-05-10
8     C 2016-05-15      1  2016-05-12
9     C 2016-05-15      2  2016-05-12
10    D 2016-05-30      3  2016-05-15
11    D 2016-05-30      9  2016-05-15
```

oe you can just do

```
df %>% left_join(df%>% 
                   distinct(Team, Date) %>% 
                   mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)))
```

Comment: This also works:

`df %>% left_join({.} %>% 
                     distinct(Team, Date) %>% 
                     mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)))`

Comment: @HAVB great. +10 for that

Comment: Hey just a question what does {.} mean?

Comment: @Ian.T `.` is the argument brought through by the pipe function. OP wanted to use the same argument twice. So had to enclose the second as an expression or you to again use pipe operator on it

Answer (score 8):

Though this isn't an answer to my question (Onyambo provided that!), I wanted to share that I found an alternative way to accomplish the same thing.  Basically you use `group_by()` and `nest()` to squish the tibble and get the repeated vars out of the way, do the lag, and then `unnest()`.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Team, Date) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)) %>% 
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#>    Team  Date       Date_Lagged Points
#>    <fct> <fct>      <fct>        <dbl>
#>  1 A     2016-05-10 <NA>             1
#>  2 A     2016-05-10 <NA>             4
#>  3 A     2016-05-10 <NA>             3
#>  4 A     2016-05-10 <NA>             2
#>  5 B     2016-05-12 2016-05-10       1
#>  6 B     2016-05-12 2016-05-10       5
#>  7 B     2016-05-12 2016-05-10       6
#>  8 C     2016-05-15 2016-05-12       1
#>  9 C     2016-05-15 2016-05-12       2
#> 10 D     2016-05-30 2016-05-15       3
#> 11 D     2016-05-30 2016-05-15       9
```

Created on 2018-06-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind swapping pipe nesting for function nesting, this accomplishes your goal:

```
df %>% left_join(mutate(distinct(., Team, Date), Date_Lagged = lag(Date)))
```

output:

```
Joining, by = c("Team", "Date")
   Team       Date Points Date_Lagged
1     A 2016-05-10      1        <NA>
2     A 2016-05-10      4        <NA>
3     A 2016-05-10      3        <NA>
4     A 2016-05-10      2        <NA>
5     B 2016-05-12      1  2016-05-10
6     B 2016-05-12      5  2016-05-10
7     B 2016-05-12      6  2016-05-10
8     C 2016-05-15      1  2016-05-12
9     C 2016-05-15      2  2016-05-12
10    D 2016-05-30      3  2016-05-15
11    D 2016-05-30      9  2016-05-15
```