# Sum up integers by group longwise in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to add the value column by id group and put the total where type = total for each id.
In the below example, the total for id = 1 would be 5 instead of NA, total for id = 2 would be 17 instead of NA.

There may be NA values that should not be included in the sum.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'total', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'total'), value = c('1', NA, '4', NA, '5', '4', '8', NA))


 id  type value
  1     A     1
  1     B  <NA>
  1     C     4
  1 total  <NA>
  2     A     5
  2     B     4
  2     C     8
  2 total  <NA>
```

This would be the desired output:

```
 id  type value
  1     A     1
  1     B  <NA>
  1     C     4
  1 total     5
  2     A     5
  2     B     4
  2     C     8
  2 total    17
```

From what I know, group_by() is the first step towards the answer? But I am not sure how to use the values in the group to assign it to the total. Maybe colSums()?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add baseline/grand total with group\_by() in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090929/add-baseline-grand-total-with-group-by-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 1):

This should work and I think clear enough.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    value = as.numeric(value),
    value = if_else(type == 'total', sum(value, na.rm = T), value)
  )
```

Another option that is worth reading about is the `janitor` package.

Answer (score 0):

I you do not mind starting from a dataframe without the total lines you could do the following:

```
# I changed your data so value is of type numeric, you could use mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) if necessary
# and there is no total anymore as the code creates this line from raw data

df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 type = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'), 
                 value = c(1, NA, 4, 5, 4, 8))

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            type = "total") %>% 
  bind_rows(., df) %>% 
  # some sorting for a better looking table
  select(id, type, value) %>% 
  mutate(type = forcats::fct_relevel(.f = type, "total", after = Inf)) %>% 
  arrange(id, type)

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>      id type  value
#>   <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
#> 1     1 A         1
#> 2     1 B        NA
#> 3     1 C         4
#> 4     1 total     5
#> 5     2 A         5
#> 6     2 B         4
#> 7     2 C         8
#> 8     2 total    17
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>