# R: How to Ungroup a Data Frame to Get a Pivot Table That Shows a Grand Total

Tags: r, pivot-table

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
print(as_tibble(working_df), n = 3)

 ride_id          bike_type   started_at          ended_at            start_sta_name                    start_sta_id
  <chr>            <chr>       <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>                             <chr>       
1 23697816035F9A8F docked_bike 2022-03-05 19:08:00 2022-03-29 15:43:00 Sheffield Ave & Fullerton Ave     TA1306000016
2 DC510E6F98003A94 docked_bike 2022-07-04 18:37:00 2022-07-27 00:32:00 Dusable Lake Shore Dr & Monroe St 13300       
3 578BA30BA1348F18 docked_bike 2022-01-01 01:00:00 2022-01-21 08:51:00 Millennium Park                   13008       
  end_sta_name                    end_sta_id                          start_lat start_lng end_lat end_lng user_type ride_length
  <chr>                           <chr>                                   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1 Base - 2132 W Hubbard Warehouse Hubbard Bike-checking (LBS-WH-TEST)      41.9     -87.7    41.9   -87.7 Casual          34355
2 Green St & Randolph St*         chargingstx3                             41.9     -87.6    41.9   -87.6 Casual          32035
3 Fairfield Ave & Roosevelt Rd    KA1504000102                             41.9     -87.6    41.9   -87.7 Casual          29271
  day_of_week
  <ord>      
1 Saturday   
2 Monday     
3 Saturday
```

I want to create a pivot table that provides a the average ride length of the users per group and an average of all of my users together (a "grand total").  I created one using SQL with the following code:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(user_type, 'combined') AS user_type,
    ROUND(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, started_at, ended_at)), 2) AS avg_ride_length_min
FROM 
    bikes.work
GROUP BY
    user_type WITH ROLLUP;
```

[[image: The code above gave me the following response]]

What is the best approach to do this in R?  I tried the code below but it did not work:

```
working_df %>% 
  select(user_type, ride_length) %>% 
  group_by(user_type) %>% 
  summarize(avg_ride_length = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(mean(ride_length))
```

My research showed me that the `rpivotTable::rpivotTable()` could work, so I installed the `htmlwidgets`, `knitr`, and `rpivotTable` packages.  I tested the function on the Titanic dataset and it worked, but when I loaded my data frame on the function, the RStudio Viewer panel grayed out.  Maybe my data frame is too big for it to work.  Is there an alternative to this package?  Thank you so much for the suggestions.

Comment: `bind_rows(working_df %>% group_by(user_type) %>% summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length)), working_df %>% group_by(user_type = "combined") %>% summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length)))`

Comment: From my POV dplyr is more oriented toward tidy analysis vs. presentation, so I haven't seen options equivalent to "WITH ROLLUP" which mix different granularities of data and create (purposeful) duplication -- you generally have to roll your own.

Comment: TIL about SQL's `rollup`, thanks. (And while this is not the most frequent request on SO, I've seen it several times, enough that I wonder why it _isn't_ yet in `dplyr` or `tidyr`.)

Comment: @JonSpring thank you for your help.  Your solution works.  I was thinking that the second `group_by(user_type = "combined")` would separate the records into two groups, but that's just a placeholder to change the value to "combined," right?  I agree with your statement.  I saw other packages that create pretty summary tables, or pivot tables, so I thought I would need to install a new package.  Thank you!

Comment: @r2evans SQL was the first language I learned, so it makes a lot of sense to me.  It also helps that there is a common structure (SELECT FROM WHERE etc.).  R and Python feel like the wild west.  I feel you can do anything, in any order, and still come up with a solution.  WITH ROLLUP is great for doing small SQL-based reports to management.  I am glad I was able to help!

Comment: I thought I was "decent" to slightly above average on SQL, and whenever I learn a new verb or adjective for sql queries, I remind myself of my simple mortality and that SQL is a complex language. Having said that, there are many things that SQL does not do well; pivoting/reshaping comes to mind, as do many rolling calculations. Not to say that they cannot be done, just that it is a lot harder there. Thanks for letting me be [one of 10,000](https://xkcd.com/1053/) today!

Comment: One potential duplicate question with similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090929/add-baseline-grand-total-with-group-by-in-dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two variations on the solution in my comment:

```
set.seed(42)
working_df <- data.frame(user_type = c("A", "Z"),
           ride_length = rpois(10, 10))

bind_rows(
  working_df %>% group_by(user_type) %>% 
    summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length)), 
  working_df %>% group_by(user_type = "combined") %>% 
    summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length)))


bind_rows(working_df, working_df %>% mutate(user_type = "combined")) %>%
  # this is to put "combined" last
  mutate(user_type = factor(user_type) %>% 
           forcats::fct_relevel("combined", after = Inf)) %>%
  # .by introduced in dplyr 1.1.0
  summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length), .by = "user_type")


  user_type avg_ride_length_min
1         A                13.2
2         Z                 9.4
3  combined                11.3
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Thank you for your reply. I saw your comment, and I think that answer can be used to create multiple subtotals and totals. I'll give it a spin tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Hello.  I applied your solution to my code:

`working_df %>% 
  select(user_type, ride_length) %>% 
  group_by(user_type) %>%
  summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate_at(c("user_type"), list(~as.character(.))) %>% 
  bind_rows(summarize(user_type = "Combined", working_df, avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length)))`

I want to confirm the meaning of the ~ and  the .  The ~ is saying the list function is the dependent variable, and the independent variable is the as.character function?  Does the period represent working_df?

Comment: I'd suggest using `mutate(user_type = as.character(user_type))` or `mutate(across(user_type, as.character))`; `mutate_at` is deprecated, I believe.